# how i can pass array argument to C++ function

Tags: binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I want to pass an array from one object, store reference and then work with this array inside my function, but...

I have a terrible misunderstanding of passing an array process: In the class TreeType.

I’m facing with an error and I have tried to resolve that for 3 days, but I couldn’t.

Function:

```
void AddElements(TreeType& tree, int info[], int fromIndex, int toIndex)

{
int midIndex;

if (fromIndex <= toIndex)
{
   midIndex = (fromIndex + toIndex) / 2;
  tree.PutItem(info[midIndex]);
  AddElements(tree, info, fromIndex, midIndex - 1);
  // Complete the left subtree.
  AddElements(tree, info, midIndex+1, toIndex);
   // Complete the right subtree.
 }
}
 void MakeTree(TreeType& tree, int info[], int length)
  // Creates a binary tree from a sorted array.
{
 tree.MakeEmpty();
  int arrayb[length];

  for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
 {
    cout << "Enter Value to make tree:" << endl;
    cin >> arrayb[i];
 }


AddElements(tree, info, 0, length-1);
}
```

And invoked in main.cpp.

```
else if (command == "MakeTree")
  {
     int length=25;
     //int arrayb[length];
     int arrayb[]={-1000,-967,-923,-844,-669,-567,-455,-267,-209,-183,-59,-23,68,132,159,170,222,228,233,241,389,479,824,939,985};
tree.MakeTree(tree,arrayb,length);
```

[Error capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgaWd.jpg)

Comment: `void MakeTree(TreeType& tree, int *info, int length)`

Comment: I changed as you direct, But still it's not working. 
what  should I do now?